# plot data using nested loop in matplotlib

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I am trying to create line chart for each data created by nested loop.
This is the first five rows of the main dataframe:
[image]
There are three unique countries in "Country" column. I want for each country to plot "hum","pre" and "temp" data separately. So there should be 9 charts (3x3).

This is my code:

```
fig,axes=plt.subplots(3,3,figsize=(15,15))
for country in df.Country.unique():
    for i in ["pre","hum","temp"]:
        for ax in axes.ravel():
            grouped=df[(df.Country==country)&(df.year==2016)].groupby("date")[i].mean().reset_index().sort_values("date")
            grouped.plot(ax=ax,kind="line",x="date",y=i,xlabel="")
            ax.set_title(i+" for "+country,size=10)
plt.show()
```

I get nine charts but all like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to plot on a single axis for each combination of country and variable.

```
fig,axes=plt.subplots(3,3,figsize=(15,12)) 
    for j, country in enumerate(df.Country.unique()):
        for i, var in enumerate(["pre","hum","temp"]):
            ax = axes[i, j]
            grouped=df[(df.Country==country)&(df.year==2016)].groupby("date")[var].mean().reset_index().sort_values("date")
            grouped.plot(ax=ax,kind="line",x="date",y=var,xlabel="")
            ax.set_title(var+" for "+country,size=10)
plt.show()
```